# Zip file with first file empty

Tags: java

I am trying to create a .zip file with multiple files in it. The problem is that when I open the .zip file, the first selected file (when the files are picked using the JFileChooser) is always empty (the file is created but has a small size) while the other files are ok.

I can not figure out where the problem might be in my code.

```
fileName = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    String zipFile="E:\\test.zip";
                    FileOutputStream fout = null;
                    try {
                        fout = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    ZipOutputStream zout=new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fout));

                    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){

                    try {
                            outFilename = fileName.getAbsolutePath()+".zip";
                            System.out.println(s[i]);
                            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(s[i]);
                            zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(s[i].getName()));
                            System.out.println(s[i].getName());
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                            while ((len = in.read(buf, 0 , 1024)) > 0)
                        {
                                zout.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }
                        zout.closeEntry();
                        in.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {}}
                    try {
                        zout.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Never write an empty `catch` block.  *At the very least,* put `e.printStackTrace();` in there.  Really, though, you should remove all of your `catch` blocks and enclose the entire sequence of code in a single try…catch (IOException).  If you can’t open the zipFile, it really doesn’t make sense to continue, does it?

Comment: I am sorry if i didn't make my self clear. I can open the zip file, it is about the files inside the zip. The 2nd and 3rd file work accordingly, the first file added has issues. http://imgur.com/a/GeojP this is what it looks like.

Comment: If you suppress IOExceptions, it’s entirely possible that something is going wrong with writing the zip file and you aren’t aware of it.